# Calling a function on distinct values from table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I've got a SQL Server 2005 database.  I need to get distinct values in addition to calling a function on those distinct values.  I'm not sure how the distinct works when there is a function call involved.  For example, I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, fcn_DoSomething(a, b, c) AS z FROM users
```

I'm guessing that the function (fcn_DoSomething) is being called for all of the values in the table, not the distinct values.  Am I correct?  If so, how can I write the query to call the function only on distinct values of a,b,c?  I know one option is to use a temporary table, but if anyone has better ideas that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would ensure that the function only got called on distinct values.

```
select *, fcn_DoSomething(a, b, c) 
from
 (select distinct a,b,c FROM users) v
```

However, I believe that the function call will be optimised, so it may not make a difference. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

This got me curious, so I did a bit of basic testing.  I created a small table with some distinct and some repeating values, a function that just does string concatenation, and then looked at the execution plans for:

```
Go
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS 
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE 


select distinct cola, colb, dbo.sillyfunc(cola, colb)
from distincttest

--Clear the cache
Go
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE 

select cola, colb, dbo.sillyfunc(cola, colb)
from (select distinct cola, colb from distincttest) as t
```

In this case, the execution plans showed clearly that the first one ran the concatenation function for every single row, but the second did the sort for distinct values first, then ran the function.  But for a small number of rows, they had the same execution time, and when run together they showed each one using 50% of the total query resources.

So, I added a few hundred thousand repeating rows. and tried again.  This changed the query plan so it was doing a hash match to get distinctness rather than the former sort, and now the second version which forced it to select for distinctness first executed more than ten times faster.

Finally, I thought there was a chance that this might just be because SQL Server had my sillyfunc marked as nondeterministic (`select OBJECTPROPERTYEX(object_id('dbo.sillyfunc'), 'isdeterministic')` returned 0), so I switched to [patindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) which was a builtin function and considered deterministic.  This gave me the same results with the function being called for every row in the first version and just for the few distinct ones in the second version.

So, its possible that further testing would find situations that would coax the optimizer to do something more sophisticated, but it appears that if you want to apply the distinct before the function is called then you need to use something like a subquery, CTE, or temp table to limit what the function has access to.